# Error occur while launching titanium project

Tags: android, titanium

When I run my titanium project, the console prints

```
[ERROR] :  Emulator process exited with code 1

[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1

[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 191ms
```

Comment: have u android sdk 2.2 installed ?

Answer (score 0):

"It turned out you need not only the current Android-SDK, but also 2.3.3 (or 2.1) installed (including Android Tools). Now it works for me"

From here:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153261/emulator-process-exited-with-code-1---cant-compile-apk

Answer (score 0):

This is the most beaten topic an appcelerator form.If u have taken a good search you have found plenty of links.Here are they

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153261/emulator-process-exited-with-code-1---cant-compile-apk

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/151293/emulator-problem

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/151834/build-process-exited-with-code-1

Usually it occurs because of absence of android sdk 2.2 but if you have already installed try to give the project clean build

Thanks

Comment: I install Android 2.2 API 8 But Still Get the same Error ,Is there any other way? PLs help me

Comment: What are you trying device or emulator?